# FinancialData and RandomChoice from list

Tags: functions, string-manipulation

I am trying to extract a random stock name from my list of stocks and run FinancialData to find stock price. I know FinancialData requires double quotation marks (ex. FinancialData["AAV"]) in order to work. Is there a way to make FinancialData work using RandomChoice inside of it?

Here is my code, it is outputting FinancialData[{AAV}] and therefore not working.

```
stocks = {"AAV", "ABX", "AC.B", "VET", "VRX", "VSN", "WFT",
"WJA", "WJX", "WPT", "WTE", "X", "YRI"}

FinancialData[RandomChoice[stocks,1]]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: By default, quotation marks are not shown in output cells. The curly braces are the problem. You can use ,e.g., `FinancialData[First@RandomChoice[stocks, 1]]` or `FinancialData[Sequence @@ RandomChoice[stocks, 1]]` to remove them. Furthermore, some of your stock symbols are not valid (try `FinancialData /@ stocks`), you'll have to add an exchange for those. For example, `"VSN"` should be replaced with `"TO:VSN"`.